# Error while type casting Webelement to Select

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

1. In my web page there are multiple `dropdowns` with same property valuesto
2. I am getting all those `Webelements` in a List
3. Now fetching one `WebElement` from the List using index
4. While trying to type cast this `WebElement` to Select I am getting error:

> "java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select"

Please Help! Below is my code.

```
int index;
String sIndex = null;
By element = ORUtils.ORGenerator(pageName,objectName);
//Getting all the webelements with same name in myElement List
java.util.List<WebElement> myElements=WebUtils.driver.findElements(element);

//Get index of element on page
Pattern pIndex=Pattern.compile("(.*)");
Matcher mIndex=pIndex.matcher(objectName);
if(mIndex.find())
{
    sIndex=objectName.replaceAll("[a-z]","");
    sIndex=sIndex.replaceAll("[A-Z]","");
}

index=Integer.valueOf(sIndex);
index=index-1;
//Getting element from the List using index
WebElement myElement=myElements.get(index);

//Type casting WebElement to Select this is where i get the error**
Select myDropDown=(Select) myElement;

List<WebElement> listOfOptions = myDropDown.getOptions();
//List<WebElement> listOfOptions=myElement.
for(WebElement item : listOfOptions)
{
    if(Value.equals((item.getText())))
    {
        item.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In java object typecasting one object reference can be type cast into another object reference. The cast can be to its **own class type or to one of its subclass or superclass types or interfaces**. So what you are doing is incorrect. To create object of Select using myElement do:

```
Select myDropDown=new Select(myElement);
```

To know more you can also try out by looking `instanceOf`. Here you can check it as:

```
if (myElement instanceof Select)
    System.out.println(true);
else
    System.out.println(false);
```

and you will get your answer.